# How can i automate the install / uninstall process of a joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

Currently i develop a joomla 1.7 component. Each time i want to test the component, make a zip from my component source folder and install it into my joomla system. After testing i uninstall the component, code some stuff and redo the process.

Is there a way to make it more easy?

Comment: Here's something I've done that might be helpful to you (depending on your environment): Since different parts of the component go to different parts of the Joomla installation, I create a bash script that basically uploads to my server via ssh the changes I made, to the different locations. Language files go to the language dir, the component itself goes to a different directory, etc. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to zip then you can use Install Directory
[image]

Comment: I am already doing it that way, but i do not want to click install every time i have changed something. Thanks anyway

Comment: Today i just tryed to install again without uninstalling it before ... What should i say it works well. I can live with one button press

Answer (score 1):

You can get some detail from [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) doc. It includes some topics regarding development process.

Comment: I know this site, but have not found any useful yet. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since you are installing/uninstalling I assume that you are testing that part of your application. I would suggest using the method described by Doers above.

If you just want to create a working installer and focus on the core logic of your application you can give our Joomla Component Creator a spin. https://www.component-creator.com/en/

Comment: That thing is very cool stuff! Next time i will use it to save alot of time. But was not what i was looking for :)